# Outlook 2003 VB Script to create forwarding rule

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

Hello does anyone know how to create a VB Script that will add a rule in Outlook 2003 such that if I receive an email from user PersonA@mail.com it will forward that email to PersonB@mail.com.

I would also like to know if it possible to create a VB Script to remove the previously created rule.

I've done a little research and it seems possible to create a macro to do this, but I am completely lost as I am not familiar with the objects I need to be editing or have any sort of API.

Maybe I have to create a Macro to add the rules and this use a VB script to fire the Macro.

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, you can use the Rules Wizard -- no VBA required.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a one time thing.  I need to constantly be changing the rules, so I need to be able to remove and readd them.  I figured a script would be a nice way to centrally control them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use straight VBA instead. The [ItemAdd Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171270%28v=office.11%29.aspx) can be used to check your default Inbox for incoming messages and forward them. It is simple to edit the email addresses if you need to change the forwarding.

Ex:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Application_Startup() 
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
End Sub
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 
On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
Dim newMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient

' *****************
' edit these to change forwarding rules
' *****************
Const INCOMING_EMAIL As String = "Persion@mail.com"
Const OUTGOING_EMAIL As String = "PersonB@mail.com"

If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
Set Msg = item
  If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = INCOMING_EMAIL Then
    Set newMsg = Msg.Forward

    With newMsg
      Set recip = .Recipients.Add OUTGOING_EMAIL
      recip.Type = olTo
      .Send
    End With
    ' *****************
    ' perhaps a msgbox?
    ' MsgBox "Message forwarded", vbInformation
    ' *****************
  End If
End If
ProgramExit: 
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
Resume ProgramExit 
End Sub
```

This code should be placed in ThisOutlookSession module, then you must restart Outlook. If you need placement assistance see [Where do I put my Outlook VBA code?](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/outlook-vba/where-do-i-put-my-outlook-vba-code/)